# bash variables in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a python script conve_cal.py which take 7 arguments as follow:

```
enter code here
import numpy as np
import sys

def read_file(filename1,filename2):
    Input1 = np.loadtxt(filename1)
    Input2 = np.loadtxt(filename2)
    #print type(Input1)
    #print Input1
    return Input1,Input2

def NU_calc(T_avg,Trght,Ttop,rmv,argv1,argv2,arg3):
    ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    T_avg = sys.argv[1]
    Trght = sys.argv[2]
    Ttop = sys.argv[3]
    rmv = sys.argv[4]
    arg3 = sys.argv[5]
    file1 = sys.argv[6]
    file2 = sys.argv[7]
    print (sys.argv)
    In1,In2 = read_file(file1,file2)
    #print type(arg3)
    NU_calc(T_avg,Trght,Ttop,rmv,In1,In2,arg3)
```

If I run the code stand alone in the Terminal as

```
python2 conve_calc.py 285 282 300 0 noclip Input1.dat Input2.dat
```

the code give the output as desired. But If i use the same syntax with bash variables in the bash script as follows;

```
#!/bin/bash
...
...
t_avg=`grep "Average" test.avg |cut -f6 -d" "`
t_right=`grep "Tright" ./0/Input_conditions|cut -f 3 |cut -f 1 -d';'`
t_top=`grep "Ttop" ./0/Input_conditions|cut -f 3 |cut -f 1 -d';'`

echo "$t_right $t_top $Hr $Ht" >> $start_path/post_process_data/'HT_stat.dat'

rm test.avg tmp.dat test_fl.txt

# Call 
# Arg-1; Average Temp
## Arg-2; Temp of right wall
## Arg-3; Temp of top wall 
## Arg-4; # of faces to remove (0:None ,1...upto max of no. of faces)
## Arg-5; Right GradT file
## Arg-6; Top GradT file

rv0="0" # Change this to Remove the faces
rv1="1"
c1="noclip"
c2="middle"
i1="Input1.dat"
i2="Input2.dat"

python2 $start_path/conve_calc.py $t_avg $t_right $t_top $rv1 $c1 $i1 $i2 >> $start_path/post_process_data/\
'Common_out.dat'
```

But with this bash script input I am getting Following error I am unable to find why these inputs are getting wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/meisu/OpenFOAM/meisu-2.4.0/Cyence_data/foam_adagio/conve_calc.py", line 69, in <module>
    file2 = sys.argv[7]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have looked into various stack solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: Print out all of your variables. If one of those calculated values ended up empty, you wouldn't have 7 parameters any more.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you verified that `t_avg`, `t_right` and `t_top` have what you expect? Most likely, one of those is the empty string.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: try enclosing the arguments in double quotes: `python2 $start_path/conve_calc.py "$t_avg" "$t_right" "$t_top" "$rv1" "$c1" "$i1" "$i2" >> ...`

Comment: @Pynchia : I did Tried your option but then the sys.arg[2] was reported faulty.

Comment: @BryanOakley : To debug I did printed out the values of the variable on the screen with the python script and echoed it in the Bash script as well.

Comment: @tdelaney: I used print(sys.argv) in python code to see the values which I give using terminal command and it works fine. But when I use in the Bash script the error is the same as i reported above.

Comment: @Cyrus : Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You need to echo them in bash. `echo python2 $start_path/conve_calc.py $t_avg $t_right $t_top $rv1 $c1 $i1 $i2` is sufficient if you run the bash script from the command line.

Comment: @tdelaney : As your suggestion  echo $t_avg $t_right $t_top $rv1 $c1 $i1 $i2     output:   280.00 285.00 1 noclip Input1.dat Input2.dat

Comment: Notice that you have 7 variables but when you echo, there's only 6? It means one of them is empty. You could echo each variable to see which one is causing problems. But @Pynchia's suggestion already gave you a hint. The fault argv[2] likely means that `"$t_right"` evaluated to `""` (empty) and that's why its invalid.

Comment: @tdelaney : I have 7 variable and I have echoed 7 of them. sys.arg[0] is always the script name and then  sys.arg[1-7] are my inputs to the script.

Comment: If you were quoting correctly, you wouldn't have to worry about the number of variables and the number of arguments failing to match. Always, *always* put expansions of shell variables in quotes.

Comment: @Him.sharma, try to be in the habit of using `printf '%q\n'` rather than `echo` when you want to know how things are split into arguments -- you can't tell the difference in output between `echo "hello world"` and `echo "hello" "world"`, even though they're very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that one of the variables is empty. The shell expands the variables and then parses the command so it thinks there are only 6 parameters for the command. You could add two types of defensive coding. First, for the derived variables likely to fail, test them before you use them. Second, enclose your parameters in quotes so that empty parameters, or parameters with characters such as spaces that will mess up the command parsing, will be handed down properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
...
t_avg=`grep "Average" test.avg |cut -f6 -d" "`
if [ -z "$t_avg" ]; then
    echo t_avg failed >&2
    exit 2
fi

t_right=`grep "Tright" ./0/Input_conditions|cut -f 3 |cut -f 1 -d';'`
if [ -z "$t_right" ]; then
    echo t_right failed >&2
    exit 2
fi

t_top=`grep "Ttop" ./0/Input_conditions|cut -f 3 |cut -f 1 -d';'`
if [ -z "$t_top" ]; then
    echo t_top failed >&2
    exit 2
fi

echo "$t_right $t_top $Hr $Ht" >> $start_path/post_process_data/'HT_stat.dat'

rm test.avg tmp.dat test_fl.txt

# Call 
# Arg-1; Average Temp
## Arg-2; Temp of right wall
## Arg-3; Temp of top wall 
## Arg-4; # of faces to remove (0:None ,1...upto max of no. of faces)
## Arg-5; Right GradT file
## Arg-6; Top GradT file

rv0="0" # Change this to Remove the faces
rv1="1"
c1="noclip"
c2="middle"
i1="Input1.dat"
i2="Input2.dat"

python2 $start_path/conve_calc.py "$t_avg" "$t_right" "$t_top" "$rv1" "$c1" "$i1" "$i2" >> "$start_path/post_process_data/Common_out.dat"
```

You can see exactly what is sent to your python script with a toy script that just prints its arguments and exits

```
!#/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for i, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print i, arg
print '---- end ----'
```

Comment: Thanks...    The check worked :--->>  if [ -z "$t_avg" ]; then
    echo t_avg failed >&2
    exit 2
fi